# Pink lines and dots on display Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, display

There are pink pixels and horizontal lines appearing on my display everywhere. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia-375 driver.

Can someone help me get rid of this problem please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JM4J.jpg)

EDIT: Shift to Nvidia-381 to solve it.

Comment: You can try to follow these instruction:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: It doesn't solve it. It also shows failed to write in DP or something whenever I open the flap of the laptop.